# Debugging in Visual Studio Code: Adding breakpoints during execution

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

I recently learned how to debug in Visual Studio Code and have a question regarding breakpoints. Is there any way to add a new breakpoint while the file is being debugged as well as print statements and possibly other modifications, when the execution is stopped at the previous breakpoint, and then continue the execution?

When I tried to do this, I get an error message stating: 'Unverified breakpoint. File is modified, please restart debug session.' But I think it would be more efficient if I did not have to restart the session. Does anyone know of any way this can be achieved?